# Модифицировать функции в лямбда функции Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Есть такой код:

```
private fun calc(s:String):Int
{
    var sum = 0;

        for(c in s)
        {
            if(c.toInt() < 48 || c.toInt() > 58)
            {
                println("Ошибка ввода!")
                break;
            }
            if(c.toString().toInt() % 3 == 0)
            {
                sum+=c.toString().toInt();
            }
        }
        if(sum == 0)
        {
            println("Цифрт в числе кратных 3 не было.");
        }
        else
        {
            println("Сумма цифр кратных 3 в числе ${s.toString()} = " + sum)
        }

    return sum;
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var s = readLine();
    if(s!=null)
    {
        calc(s);
    }

}
```

Нужно изменить данный функционал таким образом, чтобы условие по которому происходит отбор, можно было передавать как аргумент(Один из аргументов функции должен быть lambda со значением по умолчанию - условием, сумма цифр в числе кратных 3.

Может кто нибудь, знаком с данным функционалом на котлин и знает как решить данную задачу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта задача очень похожа на учебную, поэтому я приведу пример, описывающий основной подход к решению

```
fun main() {
    calc("my string")
    calc("not my string")
    calc("another string"){it=="another string"}
}

fun calc(s: String, myFilterFunction: (s: String) -> Boolean = { it == "my string" }) {
    if (myFilterFunction(s)) {
        println("isFiltered")
    }
}
```

Comment: что значит более сложный пример? Всё по вашему условию, передаём функцию как аргумент, также имеется реализация этого фильтра по умолчанию