# Преобразовать код в 1 строчку. KOTLIN

Tags: kotlin

Есть такой код (Считает сумму цифр в числе кратных 3):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var s = readLine();
var sum = 0;
if(s!=null)
{
    for(c in s)
    {
        if(c.toInt() < 48 || c.toInt() > 58)
        {
            println("Ошибка ввода!")
            return;
        }
        if(c.toString().toInt() % 3 == 0)
        {
            sum+=c.toString().toInt();
        }
    }
    if(sum == 0)
    {
        println("Цифр в числе кратных 3 не было.");
    }
    else
    {
        println("Сумма цифр кратных 3 в числе ${s.toString()} = " + sum)
    }
}
```

}

Нужно преобразовать его в одно выражение, без учета ввода и вывода, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Модифицировать функции в лямбда функции Kotlin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176560/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-kotlin)

Comment: Данный, вопрос отличается, тем что, в том задании нет необходимости, реализовывать выражение в одну строчку, там задача состоит в том, чтобы в качестве аргумента функции передавалась не только строка, в которой нужно посчитать сумму цифр кратных 3, но и в качестве аргумента можно было передавать условие, от которого будет изменяться результат пример:
Было условие кратно 3, стало условие кратно 2.
Здесь же задача, состоит в том, чтобы код можно было сократить до 1 строчки, с применением всего сахара языка котлин.

Comment: `s.filter { it in "369" }.map { it.toInt() }.sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"34a56b9".map(Character::getNumericValue).filter{ it.toInt() % 3 == 0 }.sum()
```

где "34a56b9" - входная строка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете объяснить пожалуйста, что делает данный кусок кода map(Character::getNumericValue)

Comment: @roxyashechka, преобразует строку в массив только с int значениями https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/character_getnumericvalue.htm . перед тем как выполнять filter нам нужно разбить строку на массив, для этого использую map, однако в фильтре нужно работать со значениями типа int, можно еще использовать .map { it.toString().toInt() }, но тогда вылетит NumberFormatException, если в строке не только числа

Comment: Понял, спасибо!